# How can I be sure Solve failed because there was no solution to be found?

Tags: equation-solving

Is there a way I can be sure that the reason *Mathematica* can't find an answer is because there isn't one, rather than because I made a mistake with the code?

The system is as follows.

```
fa[i, j] = bE k c[i, j] + bb l b[i, j] - (uE + k[i, j] + u[i, j]) a[i, j];
fb[i, j] = u[i, j] (a[i, j] + c[i, j]) - (db + bb h + bb l) b[i, j];
fc[i, j] = bb h b[i, j] + uE a[i, j] + k[i, j + 1] a[i, j + 1] - (u[i, j] + e 
           + bE k) c[i, j];
fd[i, j] = e c[i, j] - uj d[i, j];
fg       = gg - (dg + h) g;
fh       = h g + uE l - (dh + bb sum[b[i, j], {i, imax}, {j, jmax}] + bE k) h;
fk       = uE Sum[a[i, j], {i, imax}, {j, jmax}] + Sum[k[i, j] a[i, j], {i, imax}, 
           {j, jmax}] + uE l;
fl       = bE k h + Sum[u[i, j] a[i, j], {i, imax}, {j, jmax}] - (uE 
           + bb Sum[b[i, j], {i, imax}, {j, jmax}]) l;
fn       = Sum[u[i, j] d[i, j], {i, imax}, {j, jmax}] - dn n;
```

When I set the first 5 equations equal to zero and solve, everything works.

```
 sol = Flatten[Simplify[Solve[{fa[i, j] == 0, fb[i, j] == 0, fc[i, j] == 0, 
 fd[i, j] == 0, fg == 0}, {a[i, j], b[i, j], c[i, j], 
 d[i, j], g}]]]
```

But as soon as I add one of the following concentrations ($h, k, l$, or $n$ -- all of which contain summations) into the mix *Mathematica* can no longer solve the system. I'm not sure if this is because I'm doing something wrong or if there simply are no fixed points when the expressions are so complicated.

Comment: `sum` is? Did you mean `Sum`?

Comment: Ah! Yes thank you! I will edit the question. It still says "The system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." But at least now it does give some output. I imagine this means it has solved it as well as is possible, and there are no explicit solutions...

Comment: Mathematica often doesn't have methods to deal with "abstract" things, like vectors where you won't tell it how many items are in the vector or sums where you won't tell it what the  upper bound is. That may be while it is failing the first time you tell it "add some stuff but I won't tell you how many." Can you make your problem any more concrete or does it all have to be abstract?

Comment: Oh I see, thanks Bill. I can give the limits real numbers, but i can't write the functions of i,j e.g. $a[i,j]$ explicitly as a function of i,j, unfortunately. So Mathematica can find the fixed points for the first part of the system, but I will have to use pen and paper to find the rest, whenever summation is involved?

Comment: Mathematica can find SOME functions, DSolve can solve some differential equations, RSolve can solve some recurrence equations. If you could turn your question into one of those then you might have a chance, but there are no guarantees. If you could expand all your summations into a set of explicit equations and that was simple enough then there might be a chance, but I have no idea what that will look like. If you could edit your post to show how to get that maybe someone could offer some more help.